# Ionic Android keyboard hides input field at bottom

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a solution for 1 week and like nothing works.
When I click on input field in my app, keyboard opens but it hides field at the bottom.
However what I would like is it resize screen on available space and create a scroll if necessary.

Has anyone had this issue ?

Thanks